# How to Get Client Local IP and Local HostName

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Getting Local IP of Client and Host Name on java script?

below syntax getting my public ip

```
<script>

        $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=json", function (data) {

            $("#info").html("IP: " + data.ip + "");

        })

</script>
```

Comment: browsers do not give web pages access to underlying operating system - for obvious reasons

Comment: You should do it on server side via `Request`

Comment: any article how to do it ?